# How can i prove that linear function does not form a vector space basis of $\mathcal{C}\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Prove that the linear function does not form a vector space  basis  of $\mathcal{C}\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ over $\mathbb R$?

i was trying this question many times but i could not get it.
i was taking   the  scalar  multiplication and  addition property
it was showing that this vector  form  vector space
ie  it contain the zero vector

i dont know from where i have to start
if anybody help me , i would be very thankful to him

Comment: whats "the linear function?" do you mean the linear functions? If so, then every linear combination of linear functions is again linear and the function $x^2$ is not linear.

Comment: Simply, any linear combination of linear functions is weakly monotonic but not every continuous function over $[0,1]$ is weakly monotonic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any linear combination of linear functions is still a linear function. Since the function $q\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $q(x)=x^2$ is not linear, it does not belong to the span of the linear functions.

Besides, the set of all linear functions is not linearly independent.

Comment: @lomberlego If my answer was useful, then you could mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: when it comes to $C[0,1]$ it is conventional to define a set of functions being a basis if it's span is dense, but a limit of linear functions is again linear...